# the accelerometer which detect the movement of the device that want to change the ringer mode of the phone to Ringer_Mode_silent

Tags: android, accelerometer, detection

***i have an application  trying to use the accelerometer which detect the movement of the device that want  to change the ringer mode of the phone to Ringer_Mode_silent *** i realized the service which detected incoming call but i can't inderstand how to change the mode of phone in background when i move the device,please can i help me to realized this application.

public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements SensorEventListener{

```
 private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private Sensor mAccelerometre;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometre =   mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)  

Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this,ServiceReceiver.class);
          Intent serv = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceBroadcast.class);
  startService(serv);       
    }
```

});

```
  b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this,ServiceReceiver.class);
          Intent serv = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceBroadcast.class);
          stopService(serv);

}

 public void onSensorChanged()(SensorEvent event) {
    float azimuth,pitch,roll;
    if(mSensorManager==SensorManager.Sensor_Accelerometer)
     {
    azimuth = event.values[0];
    pitch = event.values[1];
    roll = event.values[2];
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.azimuth)).setText("Axe x "+azimuth);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.pitch)).setText("Axe y "+pitch);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.roll)).setText("Axe z "+roll);
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple movement detection is easy with accelerometer ( pattern detecting is difficult )just take sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) -9.81) which give you movement,where x,y,z are accelerometer readings.Compare with some threshold and change your profile mode when it crosses.

Note:

as you mentioned in your code accelerometer dont give azimuthla,roll,pitch.

values[0]: Acceleration minus Gx on the x-axis

values[1]: Acceleration minus Gy on the y-axis

values[2]: Acceleration minus Gz on the z-axis